# RPi Zero W - /dev/video0

Tags: camera, raspbian-jessie, video

So I have RPi Zero w with raspiban Jessie installed, with a Flex cable connected camera.

when I run **raspistill** I am able to see an image, however when  trying to get to `ls /dev/video0`, it is not there!

tried apt-get update and apt-get upgrade.

what port is it using? is it possible to add it as video0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

raspistill / raspivid don't use /dev/video0

/dev/video0 is created by the RPF v4l2 driver. To load it use `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`or add it to /etc/modules to load it at boot

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for the response
I tried executing sudo modprobe broadcom-v4l2 but I get: modprobe: FATAL: Module broadcom-v4l2 not found.

Comment: @Gil404 Oops, that should be bcm2835-v4l2. Corrected answer.